# Не могу понять тестовое задание js

Tags: javascript

Есть тестовое задание tutu-ru (просто решил попрактиковаться )со следующим текстом:

Написать функцию dscount, которая подсчитывает количество идущих подряд символов s1 и s2 в строке, без учёта регистра. Функция должна пройти следующие тесты

И далее приводятся тесты :

```
test(dscount, ['ab___ab__', 'a', 'b'], 2);
test(dscount, ['___cd____', 'c', 'd'], 1);
test(dscount, ['de_______', 'd', 'e'], 1);
test(dscount, ['12_12__12', '1', '2'], 3);
test(dscount, ['_ba______', 'a', 'b'], 0);
test(dscount, ['_a__b____', 'a', 'b'], 0);
test(dscount, ['-ab-аb-ab', 'a', 'b'], 2);
test(dscount, ['aAa', 'a', 'a'], 2);
```

Так вот мне непонятно почему в

```
test(dscount, ['-ab-аb-ab', 'a', 'b'], 2);
```

возвращается 2 ? Вроде же подряд идут 3 раза ab ? Может я чего то не понимаю или еще доп условия какие ?

И так же непонятен последний тест `test(dscount, ['aAa', 'a', 'a'], 2);` Почему 2 , ведь если не учитывать регистр будет 3 ?

Неужели тесты неправильные вот ссылка [git](https://github.com/tutu-ru/frontend-javascript-test)?

Comment: По последнему тесту: два случая: 1) `aA`, 2) 'Aa'. Какой еще третий случай Вы тут видите?

Comment: Ок, теперь понял , с последним значит разобрался.

Comment: А вот с `['-ab-аb-ab', 'a', 'b']` действительно непонятно, я бы предположил, что в условии банальная опечатка.

Comment: Хорошо , спасибо большое за разъяснение. Вот такие у нас тестовые задания дают кривые ..., хотя это может неофициальное задание тогда можно понять.

Comment: @Romzes200677 с тестовым всё норм, там кириллица во втором `аb`.

Answer (score 1):

Да нет, всё верно. Вы посмотрите код символов и поймёте. В `-ab-аb-ab` во втором `аb` символ `а` - кириллический, а в двух других случаях латиница.

Comment: Это как-то подло

Comment: @andreymal не люблю подобные заковырки тоже. Обычно такое с символом `с` делают.

Comment: Уже бы в задании написали что с учетом кодировки, таким образом они наверно хотят понять знает ли человек о такой проблеме или нет. Вопрос спорный , но мне полезно  было узнать что такие подвохи делают в тестовых заданиях.

Comment: @Romzes200677  спорный. Я бы такое на тестовое не стал давать. Хотя, с другой стороны, это дало повод призадуматься. Т.е, вы заметили, что "вроде как должно быть 3". Такое на очном собеседование нужно спрашивать, чтоб ход мыслей оценить.

Comment: Не пойму, в чем глубокий смысл такого подвоха? Если есть возможность задавать уточняющие вопросы, то надо просто спросить, почему тут ожидается 2. Если возможности нет, то надо писать функцию согласно формулировке задания, и вменяемо написанная функция при тестах все равно тут чудесным образом выдаст 2. Это поначалу может озадачить, но тогда понять, в чем прикол, будет уже несложно.